# How to transform OpenLayers coordinate projection

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, coordinates

I have a function where I calculate the coordinates of the bounding box:

```
    map.on('moveend', function (evt) {

        let bbox = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
        console.log(bbox);

        let bbox28992 = bbox.ol.proj.transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:28992');
        console.log(bbox28992);

    });
```

The first part works fine and gives the following array in the console:

```
[480243.8079264377, 6722365.677977535, 491537.37885557255, 6739353.807513916]
```

Then I want to transform these coordinates to the EPSG:28992 coordinate system but I cannot get it to work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
ol.proj.transformExtent(bbox, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:28992')
```

The above answer supposes you already loaded proj4js and corresponding proj4js declaration for 'EPSG:28992'.

We also don't know how you load the OpenLayers and other JavaScript libraries: via a bundler like webpack or just using something like a `<script src="..."></script>`

**Edit:** a complete working sample

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.2/proj4.min.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      proj4.defs('EPSG:28992','+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs'); 
      ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0.1757812, 52.4292222]),
          zoom: 9
        })
      });
      map.on('moveend', function (evt) {

          let bbox = map.getView().calculateExtent();
          console.log(bbox);

          let bbox28992 = ol.proj.transformExtent(bbox, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:28992')
          console.log(bbox28992);
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... and tthat does not necessarily transform just the bottom left and top right coordinates supplied, if the projections are not parallel it returns an extent in which all 4 corners of the EPSG:3857 bbox will fit (which is probably what was wanted).

Comment: I load openlayers via scripts. The standard coordinate system is 3857. When i try the following code:     `map.on('moveend', function (evt) {
        let bbox = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
        console.log(bbox);

        let bbox28992 = ol.proj.transformExtent(bbox, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:28992')
        console.log(bbox28992);

    });`,  It gives the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCode' of null`

Comment: You can find the full code via: https://github.com/HASUniversity/BO_gem_Steenbergen.git

Comment: You will need to include the proj4js library (see https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js).  Then add the definition of EPSG:28992 from https://epsg.io/28992 and (as you have ol.js version 6.5.0) register it:  
`proj4.defs('EPSG:28992','+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs'); 
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);`